# For function google sheets loop

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having trouble with a looping functions. I'm not getting the results in all the cells. I'm just getting it in the last row where there is data. Here is what ai have

```
function myfunction() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp;
      var getSheet = ss.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheetData = getSheet.getSheetByName("Sheet3")
      var endRow = sheetData.getLastRow();
      for (var i=2; i <= endRow ; i++);
      if (sheetData.getRange(i,2).getValue() == "test") {
        sheetData.getRange(i,4).setValue("alert1");
      } else{
        sheetData.getRange(i,4).setValue("alert2");
      }
      }
```

[Here is an screenshot of the sheet if it helps :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFu3B.png)

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, I think that your for loop doesn't loop by `;` of `for (var i = 2; i <= endRow; i++);`. When you want to loop, please modify `for (var i = 2; i <= endRow; i++);` to `for (var i = 2; i <= endRow; i++)`.
- When `getValue` and `setValue` are used in a loop, I think that the process cost will become high. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function myfunction() {
  var getSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetData = getSheet.getSheetByName("Sheet3")
  var range = sheetData.getRange("B2:B" + sheetData.getLastRow());
  var values = range.getValues().map(([b]) => [b == "test" ? "alert1" : "alert2"]);
  range.offset(0, 2).setValues(values);
}
```

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)